# arangojs: keepNull not an option for collection.save?

Tags: javascript, arangodb, arangojs

I'm going through the documentation for arangojs and looking at the function `collection.update()`, keepNull is one of the options that can be added. https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs/blob/master/docs/Drivers/JS/Reference/Collection/DocumentManipulation.md

When going through the same documentation for the function `collection.save()` (https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs/blob/master/docs/Drivers/JS/Reference/Collection/DocumentCollection.md) we find no such option. Why? Do I first need to have an original file, then update that one with keepNull: false before I get it to clean up my documents from any null valued keys? Or is this a lack in the documentation? I think it's correct since I haven't managed to set keepNull to false using collection.save myself.

Answer (score 1):

The driver hands the query options over to the server, so this is the relevant documentation to look at:

https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/http/document-working-with-documents.html#create-document

The API does not support `keepNull` as option when creating a document. It is only available for UPDATE/REPLACE queries to mark attributes for removal. So it's up to you to do this on the client-side. You may open a feature request nonetheless.

BTW. In AQL, `UPDATE doc WITH {} OPTIONS { keepNull: false }` will not remove any attributes with a `null` value! It only removes attributes you set explicitly to `null` in the `WITH {}` part. This may apply to the driver as well.